# Change the fingerprint SHA of certificate csr

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

my website https is failing a PCI scan because of weak SHA-1 certificate Fingerprint. Please see the attached image depicting the SHA-1 fingerprint directly on the certificate....
[image]

The certificate is purchased through GoDaddy... I have tried to re-generate new private key and CSR with SHA-256 as below:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -fingerprint -sha256 -nodes -key mydomain.com.key -out mydomain.com.new.csr
```

But same result. Does anyone know how I can fore Fingerprint to be SHA-2 during the creation of the CSR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fingerprint is not an attribute in the certificate, it's a SHA-1 calculation on the certificate content.  You can't fail PCI because of a SHA-1 thumbprint.  All certs have them... and MD5 thumbprints, etc, because it's just a calculation after the fact.

What's more likely is your certificate is signed with RSA-SHA-1.  Any new certificates from public CAs should use stronger signature algorithms, so it should just be "get a new certificate".

Comment: Thank You very much `bartonjs` you have answered my question perfectly.